# Random value command not working correctly - Python

Tags: python, random

I'm using random.randint() in python , but today i noticed that something is going wrong :
The random.randint() function returns only 1 or 2 , but i set the range by 1 to 11 .
This is my script :

```
import random

while True:
        Limit1 = input("Limit 1 : ")
        Limit2 = input("Limit 2 : ")
        print("your random number is : " + str(random.randint(int(Limit1),int(Limit2)) ) )
```

There's another library or a way to solve this ?

Comment: You need to cast Limit1 and Limit2 to ints using ```int()``` (also make them lowercase to follow convention)

Comment: i wrong because i'm writing an example . I have a different script that works at the same way of this

Comment: however, the problem is that in all the scripts I use random.randint (), it always returns 1 or 2

Comment: I copied and pasted your block of code into an interactive session, and cannot reproduce the behavior you describe.  Accordingly, I've voted to close the question.

Comment: @Ale865 Unless you provide us with a real, minimal piece of code that exhibits the problem, and not something different that works as intended, there is nothing we can do. But you can be sure that the problem is in your code, and not in the `random` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
import random

while True:
    Limit1 = int(input("Limit 1 : "))
    Limit2 = int(input("Limit 2 : "))
    print("your random number is : " , str(random.randint(Limit1,Limit2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Limit` variables are string. So it should be changed to int like this:

```
import random

while True:
    Limit1 = input("Limit 1 : ")
    Limit2 = input("Limit 2 : ")
    print("your random number is : " + str(random.randint(int(Limit1), int(Limit2))))
```

Comment: look carefully , i do this

Comment: The problem is in the random() library i think

Comment: @Ale865 I have run it 3 times, first time it returns 4, second time 2 and third time 7. I couldn't reproduce your problem. Please mention your python version.

Comment: My version is Python 3.8